# Why isn't my DbContext enrolling in my TransactionScope?

Tags: vb.net, transactionscope, dbcontext

I'm using EF code first, and I can't seem to get my query to run in the context of a TransactionScope. I've seen dozens of examples of doing exactly this, and yet my insert is not transactioned; this test fails, with the record still in the DB, but no errors are thrown.

I'm on SQL 2008, and MSDTC is turned on, though my understanding is that it doesn't need to be, since this shouldn't be escalated to a distributed transaction in this environment. In any case, I think I would get an exception if it tried, and failed, to escalate.

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub CanEnrollInTransaction()
    Dim id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

    Using foo = New TransactionScope(
                TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                New TransactionOptions() With {.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable})

        Dim context = New WebPersistentDataContext()    'Subclass of DbContext

        context.WebsiteErrors.Add(New WebsiteError() With {
                                  .WebsiteId = 21,
                                  .AdditionalInformation = id,
                                  .BrowserInformation = "Unit test",
                                  .ErrorDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                                  .ErrorMessage = "Unit Test"})

        'No transaction in SQL Profiler
        context.SaveChanges()

        'Tried this too...
        'Dim objectContext = CType(context, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
        'objectContext.SaveChanges()

        'Not committing should roll back the transaction when scope is disposed
    End Using

    Dim newContext = New WebPersistentDataContext()

    If newContext.WebsiteErrors.Any(Function(e) e.AdditionalInformation = id) Then
        Assert.Fail("record is still there, transaction did not roll back")
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here? Why no transaction, much less a rollback?

Update - the context class:

```
Public Class WebPersistentDataContext
    Inherits DbContext

Public Property WebsiteErrors As DbSet(Of WebsiteError)

Public Property Websites As DbSet(Of Website)

Public Property WebSettings As DbSet(Of WebSetting)

Public Sub New()

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Can you paste the code from your WebPersistentDataContext here?